# Messages: show User Name with variable User_ID

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i have 2 tables, to create messages, conversation and messages. If you create a new message with a new partner, you get a new conversation ID, so if you started the conversation, your user_id is in the messages table and in the conversation table you are user_one your writting partner is user_two. But if somewhere else is started the conversation you are user_two and in the messages table, the user_id ist the other user.

I need the name from your writting partners to show in a list.

Example:

- Mario  / Last Message /       -> if i click so i will see the messages
- Maria  / Last Message /       -> if i click so i will see the messages

To save and show the messages is working. I need only to read the name from your conversation partner.

With my solution i get the name of the writting partners, but only if you are User two. 
The problem is the join. 
I need something like JOINNOTIN

My table: 
Conversation

```
  'id'
  'user_one'
  'user_two'
```

Messages

```
  'id'
  'message'
  'userid'
  'conversationid'
```

My Query:

```
 $messages = DB::table('conversation')
      ->select('messages.message', 'conversation.user_one', 'conversation.user_two', 'users.name', 'users.firstname', 'messages.id', 'messages.created_at', 'conversation.id')
      ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'conversation.user_one')
      ->join('messages', 'messages.conversation_id', '=', 'conversation.id')
      ->where('messages.userid', '!=', Auth::user()->id)
      ->orwhere('conversation.user_one', '=', Auth::user()->id)
      ->orwhere('conversation.user_two', '=', Auth::user()->id)
      ->groupBy('messages.conversation_id')
      ->latest()
      ->get();
```

Comment: I think you are trying to get both users name but right now only showing the logged user name right ?

Comment: I get only the user name from user_one. But is the current_user user one so i get his name but i want only the name from the conversation with the current_user. My cases the current_user can be messages.user_id and user_one. My current_user can be messages.user_id and user_two. My current_user can be only user_one or user_two. I want the name of the conversation partner from current_user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the condition `user_one == auth()->user()->id` OR `user_two == auth()->user()->id` in the `join()` method.

```
$authId = auth()->user()->id;
$messages = DB::table('conversation')
      ->select('messages.message', 'conversation.user_one', 'conversation.user_two', 'users.name', 'users.firstname', 'messages.id', 'messages.created_at', 'conversation.id')
      ->join('users', function ($join) use ($authId) {
          $join->on('id', '=', 'user_one')->orOn('id', '=', 'user_two')
          ->where('id', '!=', $authId);
      })
      ->join('messages', 'messages.conversation_id', '=', 'conversation.id')
      ->where('messages.userid', '!=', Auth::user()->id)
      ->orwhere('conversation.user_one', '=', Auth::user()->id)
      ->orwhere('conversation.user_two', '=', Auth::user()->id)
      ->groupBy('messages.conversation_id')
      ->latest()
      ->get();
```

Comment: Great. Thank you.